# How Do I know my site is not running on another tab in a same browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

How Do I know my site is not running on another tab in a same browser? Any function or script exist which is give me how many tab has running my site in a same browser?

Answer (score 1):

1. Page loads

   - Store a value in a cookie
2. Page unloads

   - Remove cookie

If at step 1. the cookie already exists then do what you need to do ;)

Very basic and naive solution!

I think there is a way to do cross tab communication, but  I can't remember what it's called... or maybe i'm dreaming.

**Edit:** The localStorage change event might also be of help

Comment: What If user close browser/tab?

Comment: Then the page unload event will be fired:

window.onunload = function(){ // Delete cookie };

Comment: @Metalstorm What about closing whole widow with X?

Comment: @LUIFA I'm guessing it will fire all the unloads... maybe... give it a go :)
If not you could have timeout on the cookie of a few seconds or minutes, and something that continuously updates/resets the cookie on the page. That should help with someone closing the whole window. That then poses the question, if you closing the entire window, then you are closing both tabs. Unless you have 2 tabs in 2 separate windows/browsers, which is different to the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

You could check is a session variable is set? this should pick up in the same browser different tab